# Copy Rotation Bone Constraint fails

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

When I add a *Single Bone* and then an *Empty* object to the scene, as follows:
[image: single bone and an empty]

Then I add a *Copy Rotation* bone-constraint, I set the *Empty* object as the target, the constraint will rotate my bone on the X axis by 90 degrees:

[image: copy rotation constraint rotating bone]

Although neither the *Armature*, nor the Bone and not even the *Empty* has any rotations whatsoever.

**My question is:** why is this happening and if this is the expected behavior, then how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, yes it is supposed to happen. If it is expected or not depends on whether on not you have read this answer. <sub>:)</sub>

The reason this happens is because bones in blender are not Z up like everything else, but the Y axis is up.

Here is a picture set up the same as yours, but with the axis display turned on for the armature.
[image: bone showing the Y axis is up]

You can easily "fix" the offset by changing the rotational space from *World* to *Local with Parent*. (You will in most cases want to use local with Parent space anyway.) 
[image: Copy rotation constraint settings]

---

Try rotating the bone in edit mode, then see what the constraint does with *Offset* turned on and the Space set to *World*. (Hint, you will end up needing Local with Parent.)

Answer (score 1):

I still have no idea why, but it looks like, that turning the `Offset` option to `True` (place a tick into the option-box) will solve the problem:

[image]